# If statement logic and arrays

Tags: c#

I have a method (in a class) which is passed 2 integers and then returns the value at that "coordinate" in a jagged array that is setup as a 2D grid. So, for example, `GetXY(5,6)` would return whatever integer value happens to be at that position.

In the method I have an if statement that checks that the passed values are not below zero or higher than the size of the array, and throws an exception with `throw new` if the values are.

The code is partly working, except that it only detects when the row is at a wrong value, and does nothing when the column is at a wrong value.

Here is my code (`grid` is created in the class constructor):

```
public int GetXY(int row, int column)
        {

            int[] items = grid[column];

            if (row < 0 || column < 0 || row >= grid.Length || column >= items.Length)
            {
                throw new Exception("The passed coordinates are outside the range of the grid. " +
                    "Passed coordinates: " + row.ToString() + "," + column.ToString() + ".");
            }

            return grid[row][column];
          }
```

When I do GetXY(10,9) (on a 10x10) grid, I get my custom exception message, except if I do GetXY(9, 10) I get:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the boun
ds of the array.
   at ProcGen.ProceduralGrid.GetXY(Int32 row, Int32 column) in C:\Users\Lloyd\do
cuments\visual studio 2010\Projects\ProcGen\ProcGen\ProceduralGrid.cs:line 127
   at ProcGen.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Lloyd\documents\visual stu
dio 2010\Projects\ProcGen\ProcGen\Program.cs:line 27
```

Why does it only work for rows? What's going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: out of bounds exception happens when you do not have that many records. Remember array index is 0 based, it might be as simple as doing a -1 for your values to look up the array

Comment: Also you really should throw more specific exception, for instance `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` or `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line is throwing the out of bounds before you get to the conditional

```
int[] items = grid[column];
```

Just move it down after you have made sure the parameters are safe:

```
public int GetXY(int row, int column)
{
    if (row < 0 || column < 0 || row >= grid.Length || column >= grid[row].Length)
    {
       throw new Exception("The passed coordinates are outside the range of the grid. " +
                "Passed coordinates: " + row.ToString() + "," + column.ToString() + ".");
    }
    return grid[row][column];
}
```

Comment: Would this work? items is being declared before the if part so that it can do items.Length?

Comment: Should be `|| column >= grid[row].Length`, since it's jagged.

Comment: @zimdanen Yeah noticed that as well, also fixed.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that works fine! How exactly does grid[row].Length work, instead of it being grid[column].Length?

Comment: @user2595033 It's grabbing the array at `grid[row]` and figuring out how big it is, the first index is the row, so `grid[column]` would be incorrect.